# Permissões para alguns comandos e não para outros

Tags: linux

Bom dia pessoal.

Talvez essa seja uma pergunta básica mas estou com uma dúvida no Linux que não consegui encontrar pesquisando no Google.

Eu tenho uma máquina Linux rodando um nginx e com dois usuários: marcos e alex.

O que eu quero é que o marcos consiga criar links de serviços na pasta /etc/systemd/system, iniciá-los, reiniciá-los e pará-los mas não possa parar outros serviços (como o próprio nginx, por exemplo).

Já o alex precisa ter acesso ao comando nginx -s reload mas não pode ter acesso ao comando nginx -s stop.

Como ficaria a configuração do sudoers para permitir esse quadro? E essa configuração seria segura?

Comment: Você pode criar um script que execute os comandos de start/reload dos serviços que você quiser e dar somente permissos a alguns usuários

Comment: É um problema interessante com uma solução pronta no SELinux: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-systemd_access_control